# Estimating hydraulic head using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to estimate hydraulic head using SRTM DEM. My objective is to calculate hydropower potential using the hydraulic head and inflow among others.

How do I get an estimate of head?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Answer (score 1):

In GIS terminology what most closely approximates what you desire is known as "Darcy Velocity and Darcy Velocity". You will find them both in the [Groundwater Toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-groundwater-tools.htm). This lecture PDF explains the relationship between the Darcy Calculation and Hydraulic Head. The [summary](http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~martins/climate_water/lectures/darcy.html) from Columbia University explains the relationship between Darcy's Law and Hydraulic Head. the GIS software most often used is [GMS](http://www.xmswiki.com/wiki/GMS:GMS) and not ArcGIS as Hydraulic Head is most often associated with groundwater flow.